# SQLite query, 'LIKE'

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-like

I am trying to retrieve information from my database.
I have words like `Lim Won Mong` and `Limited`.

If I do my query, `SELECT name FROM memberdb WHERE name LIKE '%LIM%'`, it displays both `Lim Won Mong` and `Limited` and I only want data from `Lim Won Mong`.

How should I rewrite my query?

Comment: You mean you want it to only have the WORD "Lim" in it?

Comment: Yes, but the Lim can be at anywhere of the word as I also have "Wang Tat Lim"

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Execute following Query:

```
select name from memberdb where name like '% LIM %' OR name like "LIM %" OR name like "% LIM" OR name like "LIM"
```

Comment: Note that this would not match if the string was simply "lim". (This would still technically be a whole word.)

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
SELECT name 
FROM MEMBERDB 
WHERE name LIKE 'LIM %' OR name LIKE '% LIM'
OR name LIKE '% LIM %' OR name LIKE 'LIM';
```

Suppose you have data something like this:

```
'LIMITED'
'Lim Won Mong'
'Wang Tat Lim'
'ELIM TED'
'lim'
'Wang LIM tim'
```

This query will return you only following data:

```
'Lim Won Mong'
'Wang Tat Lim'
'lim'
'Wang LIM tim'
```

## [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/96f9c/2)

Comment: Still this wont return results in middle of string, please check my answer.

Comment: Try Your query With Hey, Lim Won Mong

Answer (score 4):

If you want to match the word "lim" (so it matches "a lim", "lim a", "a lim a", and "lim", but not "limit" or "alim"), you can use the SQL `REGEXP` keyword, and use word boundaries (`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`). These match whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines), string start/end, and some punctuation, as well.

Something like this:

```
SELECT name FROM memberdb WHERE name REGEXP '[[:<:]]LIM[[:>:]]'
```

Note that `REGEXP` is NOT case-sensitive (unless using binary strings).

If you want it to match ONLY spaces, you can still use `REGEXP`; this will match either the start of the string or a space, then "lim", then a space or the end of the string:

```
SELECT name FROM memberdb WHERE name REGEXP '(^| )LIM( |$)'
```

Both solutions have been tested on SQL versions which support `REGEXP` (SQLite 3+; all of Android uses 3.5.9 or higher).

Comment: Trying this on android and am getting an error when trying to run REGEXP keyword. It is throwing "SQLiteException: ICU error: uregex_open()" as an exception. Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: @ocross Nope, doesn't ring a bell. You'll probably want to start a new question.

Comment: Okay thanks did you have to do anything specific to get REGEXP keyword to work with Android. Reading around it sounds like it is not supported by default.