# MySQL WHERE match a concatenated string with a string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE (audience like '%Internal%20Medicine%') and ('$date' < end_date) order by end_date
```

In the database the audience column looks like this "Internal Medicine, Neurology, Radiology".

I need the query to match the exact string in between the commas.

Comment: How are you building that query?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12613926/1438733), which does the same thing but with space delimiting. Basically you want to match `%,X`, `X,%`, `%,X,%` and `X`, where `X` is the search string. You could also do a regex search, but that's not as efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE find_in_set('Internal Medicine', replace(audience, ', ', ',')) > 0 and ('$date' < end_date)
order by end_dat;
```

Comment: Awesome! I tried the find_in_set before and it didn't work, I guess I didn't realize the the spaces after the commas mattered.