# Sql Lite Query will return 0 records on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, sqlite, android-5.1.1-lollipop

So I understand the version of sql on lollipop changed (http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_0.html) , I studied that release list but still cannot figure out why my query fails. Its a simply query really:

```
select * from Lists where Name LIKE 'test' AND _Group LIKE ''
```

I'm on Android 5.1.

Comment: Is this query working fine on test data ?

Comment: I would expect the subexpression `_Group LIKE ''` to be true when the value of `_Group` is the empty string.  Are you not seeing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***What is the sample data that you *think* matches this search criteria?***

Usually `"LIKE"` contains a wildcard,

e.g. `LIKE "test%"`.

In your case, instead of the two `LIKE` you can use `"="`.

Here is a good example of using `LIKE` [SQLite query, 'LIKE'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613926/sqlite-query-like)

Comment: Yeah it was the LIKE, this worked fine it versions prior to Lollipop, and yes in this case I actually did not need the LIKE