# Android Sqlite Database Formation

Tags: android, mysql, database, android-sqlite

In my application I take entry from user as :-

```
Name:- -------------------------
Favorite Fruit:-  a)
                  b)
                  c)
                     --------- Add More ----------
```

Then I want to save it into a Sqlite database. Now I provide user to type in edittext search like this:-

```
Search Fruit:- Apple,Banana
```

And then I want to query my database and Print the name of those who like atleast Apple and Banana.

Now my issue is how do I make my database columns to achieve results faster.
Should I make two columns **Name** and **FruitsLiked** or something else. Because if I make only two colums then how do I search into database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create one table n two columns. First column is for name , second one comma separated list of fruits.

Then as db query use `like` keyword based query

Comment: So if suppose one row is NAME --- Mango,Pear,Banana,Orange,Apple     and  user search  for apple,banana then will that be achieved using like keyword

Comment: Yes.. Like works like pattern matcher. I would rather suggest you to use only one column and handle strings. ( json my suggestion )

Comment: Could you please help me framing query for this. I am not able to use LIke keyword in query.

Comment: 1. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.html, 
2. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html,
3.http://stackoverflow.com/a/12613978/793943