# SQLite Search Query

Tags: sqlite, ionic2

I want to Search from Local Storage , What will be the Sqlite Query for Ionic2 for this-
What will be the sql query for searching a number from local storage.
Something like this- 
select row_id from mytable where * like '%searched_text%';

```
 var searchmobile=newvalue
          this.database.executeSql("SELECT mobile_no FROM customer WHERE mobile_no like ?",
            [searchmobile]).then((customerdata) =>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613926/sqlite-query-like

Comment: @suraj I have to pass a variable "searchmobile", how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating `searchmobile` like:

```
 var searchmobile=newvalue
          this.database.executeSql("SELECT mobile_no FROM customer WHERE mobile_no like ?",
            ['%' + searchmobile + '%']).then((customerdata) =>
```

Answer (score 0):

u need to open the database before executing a query

```
`var searchmobile=newvalue
this.database = new SQLite();
this.database.openDatabase({
        name: "data.db",
        location: "default"
      }).then(() => {
this.database.executeSql("SELECT mobile_no FROM customer WHERE mobile_no like ?",
            [searchmobile]).then((customerdata) =>`
```